# Reason behind deprecating the Thread's stop(), destroy(), resume() methods

Tags: java, android

I read that the Thread class stop(),destroy(),resume() methods been depricated. As a reason it says:

"Because stopping a thread in this manner is unsafe and can leave your application and the VM in an unpredictable state"

Honestly I didn't understand the reason perfectly from the text. Can someone explain it  more clearly please (Perticularly that "VM unpredictable" and "unsafe" words )

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it unlocks all Monitors the Thread has locked, and so other Threads may access an Object with an inconsistent state.

For further infos:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Answer (score 0):

This article http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html explains the threading model used in Android.  Quoting from that page

> the Android UI toolkit is not thread-safe

Meaning if you are doing a lot of thread manipulation you can run into some pretty weird, seemingly random bugs.

Instead you should be using AsyncTasks to accomplish things that take too long for the UI thread.  This would include things like saving to and SD card, accessing a database, or sending a network request.  For more info on AsyncTasks see the article I linked to above as well as http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

`stop()` and `resume()` have been deprecated in Java for a decade or so. `destroy()` has been deprecated in Java since Java 1.5. Dalvik is simply mirroring Java's capabilities.